# Ellipsize Radio button label in Android

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, android, radio-group

I am working on an Android native app where I have a radio button group as given below side by side.

> [radio btn] Option 1 [radio btn] Option 2

Now the problem is I'm supporting few languages and the radio btn labels are larger in some languages. Hence I want to ellipsize these labels so that they are always aligned on a single line. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:singleLine="true"` properties as below,

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```